# Graphic designer / software developer contract

Tags: iphone, windows, windows-phone-8, game-center

I need to hire a graphic designer to draw some elements of my iPhone game and I am looking for some templates of draft contracts between software developer and graphic artist.

This is the first game I am developing and I am new to the industry. 
What is the typical scenario? Does the artist get paid a fixed sum or also a percentage of the sales?

Any suggestion where to start looking please? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to go to the Fourerr website and ask that question.
You can communicate with the Designer until you find exactly what
you need. There is no penalty in talking to as many Designers as
you choose.
http://www.fourerr.com/